# FCKEditor and ASP.NET CSS

Tags: asp.net, webforms, fckeditor

I've got an ASP.NET webforms project, and I want the fckeditor to use the stylesheet of the site so that people without HTML knowledge can look at the site and make changes.

Here is my current code:

```
<fckeditorv2:FCKeditor runat="server" ID="txtPageContent" Height="600"                    BasePath="~/FCKeditor/" ForceSimpleAmpersand="false" FormatOutput="false" EditorAreaCSS="../App_Themes/Professional/master.css"></fckeditorv2:FCKeditor>
```

As you can see, I've set the EditorAreaCSS property but it still doesn't put up the styles.

Instead of the ../App_Themes I've tried ~/App_Themes and /App_Themes but nothing.

The stylesheet certainly exists, and I've tried setting this in both the code behind and in the ASPX file.

When looking at the source, I get this in the hidden field that fckeditor makes:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ctl00_contentMain_txtPageContent___Config" value="ForceSimpleAmpersand=false&amp;EditorAreaCSS=../App_Themes/Professional/main.css&amp;FormatOutput=false&amp;HtmlEncodeOutput=true" /><iframe id="ctl00_contentMain_txtPageContent___Frame" src="/eJs.Web/FCKeditor/editor/fckeditor.html?InstanceName=ctl00_contentMain_txtPageContent&amp;Toolbar=Default" width="100%" height="600px" frameborder="no" scrolling="no">
```

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help. Probably best would be set it from code behind

EditorAreaCSS = this.ResolveUrl("~/App_Themes/Professional/main.css")

ResolveUrl() method is Page method, actually any System.Web.UI.Control should have it

Comment: I've tried that, and also /App_Themes/Professional/master.css

Comment: I didn't saw complete code I updated ny answer please check it and let me know if it works